# How to configure VNC in Linux Suse

Tags: linux, vnc, opensuse

I am trying to configure openSUSE 11.2 "Emerald" for Remote access, and having a problem

What I have done:

1. Using YaST -> Network Devices -> Remote Administering -> Allow Remote Administration
2. Firewall is disabled
3. I have installed free RealVNC on Windows XP

Problem when I try to use RealVNC to connect to:

- 192.168.XXX.XXX:5900 it gives me error "unable to connect to host: Connection refused (10061)"
- 192.168.XXX.XXX:5901 gives me a black screen with mouse pointer

In browser is the same results with just different ports 5800 and 5801

What I have missed?

**Updated:**

Yes, it worked. What I have done is:

1. Open Gnome Terminal
2. Type command "vncserver"
3. Enter client access password
4. Open File Browser -> View -> Show hidden files
5. Open ~home/.vnc folder
6. Open xstartup file in gedit
7. Replace existing code with next 2 lines:

> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> /usr/bin/gnome &
> ```

And it start working, thanks to Jed Daniels

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with the black screen - I changed from twm & to gnome & but still no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you probably are getting connected, but don't have any X desktop configured. [Check out this page](http://en.opensuse.org/VNC_HOWTO) for instructions on configuring a different desktop manager (you can probably skip the sections about installation and go right to the section on Configuring).

Answer (score 0):

Also you can configure various attributes of the VNC desktop by editing /etc/xinetd.d/vnc
(You can have multiple VNC ports with different configs. You can change dimensions and color resolution, service port, the vnc server binary (you can use a traditional X server instead of Gnome/KDE desktop with background and taskbar etc.))

Answer (score 0):

you must change X example for LXDE

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/lxsession &
```

Comment: Can you contribute more or explain how this is different from the already accepted answer?